# How to use SVN with Emacs (psvn can't create tunnel)

Tags: windows, svn, emacs

We just installed svn at my office. TortoiseSVN works (with putty to do the ssh thing--sorry if this doesn't totally make sense, I'm a total svn newbie, I always used cvs). I found psvn for emacs, which seems to be pretty standard. When I tried running it, it said it couldn't find svn. So I downloaded the client from tigris.org--which actually redirected me to a place called CollabNet which had me register a username and password just to download the svn client--still don't know what that was all about.

Anyway. Looong story short: now emacs tells me "Can't create tunnel: The system cannot find the file specified." when I try to show the revision log on a file.

Can anyone tell me how to setup svn with emacs? It doesn't have to follow the steps above, I can start again. I just want a client that'll work with emacs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the following and it works:

> Set the following environment variable
>   (by right-clicking on My Computer,
>   Properties, Advanced, Environment
>   Variables, New):-
>
> Variable name: SVN_SSH
>
> Variable value: C:\\Program Files\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\TortoisePlink.exe
>
> (The "\\" is very important, otherwise
>   it won't work. Equally, you cannot use
>   the plink.exe that comes with putty as
>   that fires up a command shell window
>   which is really annoying. The
>   TortoisePlink.exe is a windows
>   implementation of plink that doesn't
>   bring up any UI)

Source: http://www.woodwardweb.com/java/howto_configure.html

Answer (score 1):

If TortoiseSVN already works for you, try using "tortoise-svn.el"

[tortoise-svn.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/tortoise-svn.el)

[Emacs Wiki - Version Control Category](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryVersionControl)